# How to check if text widget is edited in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I want to find out how to check if the text widget in tkinter python is edited. Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have something called a "text box widget". It has an `Entry` widget and a `Text` widget. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm asking about the `Text` widget.

Comment: Suppose 'a' is added to the text box, then it is deleted.  Is it identified as "edited" or not?  You can check `edit_modified()` function provided by `Text` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk            

def text_edited(e):
    print('Current text:',t.get(1.0,tk.END))
    print(e.keysym, ' was pressed')

root=tk.Tk()                           
t=tk.Text(root)                        
t.pack()                         
t.bind('<Key>',text_edited)
```

Comment: You might want to use '<KeyRelease>' instead of '<Key>' if you want to print out the text within the key, you just pressed.